# The not so unique postgres field

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-cms

I just created a DB table (Postgresql) with Django in which a field should only accept unique entries. The problem here is that I can enter the same thing two times and it won't really throw an exception or anything. Also If I take  a look in the database the entries are identical.

My model (I'm using Django-CMS  but I don't think that it's a big difference):

```
class Newsletter(CMSPlugin):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Anrede")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Vorname")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nachname")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="E-Mail")
```

And when I generate a create command in Valentia studio through right clicking the field I get the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."boxclub-basel_newsletter" ADD COLUMN "email" CHARACTER VARYING( 100 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

Now what exactly am I doing wrong here? I mean in both Django and SQL the `UNIQUE` command is there and if i just click the field in Valentia The Unique checkbox is also checked.

Comment: Are you sure you entered the *same thing* multiple times? PostgreSQL uniqueness is case sensitive, f.ex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is unique for sure. The only explanation of this behaviour is that the values are similar but not the same. They could differ in trailing spaces for example.

You should check if your django form is properly validated.